# Case analysis on function definition in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

Imagine I have a function definition with three cases:

```
function f where 
    eq1 if cond1 
  | eq2 if cond2
  | eq3 if cond3
```

How can I prove some equation:

```
f x y = f y x
```

using case analysis on the left-hand side?

Just writing apply(cases f.cases) does not work for me. I get an error

> Undefined constant: "f"⌂

Answer (score 2):

I decided to post my comment as an answer in an attempt to close this issue.

For your use case, it should be possible to use `apply(cases ‹(x, y)› rule: f.cases)` (or similar). However, it would help to see a minimal working example before one can confirm this.

For further information about the method `cases` see section 6.5.2 "Proof methods" in Isar-ref.

Answer (score 2):

In order to complement user9716869's answer, here's a minimal working example:

```
function f where
  "f x y = 0" if "x = y" | 
  "f x y = Suc 0" if "x ≠ y"
by auto
termination by lexicographic_order

lemma "f x y = f y x"
proof (cases ‹(x, y)› rule: f.cases)
  case (1 x y)
  then show ?thesis
    by simp
next
  case (2 x y)
  then show ?thesis
    by simp
qed
```

Comment: I will upvote this, as, indeed, your answer provides some details that I omitted from my own answer. Nonetheless, of course, by a 'minimal working example' I meant an example coming from the author of the question. Without knowing the details of his application, it is impossible to tell whether `(cases ‹(x, y)› rule: f.cases)` is suitable. Of course, the error message is suggestive of the fact that the author of the question was not familiar with the syntax of the command, as described in section 6.5.2 "Proof methods".